# Directive that uses its contents as template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've having trouble building a directive that uses its content as the template.  In this particular case, the directive is making some calls to a webservice to get some child elements.  The inner html may or may not have an ng-repeat.  Here are the parts, boiled down to simplify them:

```
<div my-children="1">
  {{children.length}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="kid in children">
          {{kid.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

My expectation is that whatever is inside the element that has the directive attribute would be compiled and used for the template.

The directive (simplified) is:

```
app.directive('myChildren', function($compile, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myChildren: '='
    },
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      tElement.append(transclude(tElement));
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.children = [];

      scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
        var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
        if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
          if (fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
          }
        } else {
          this.$apply(fn);
        }
      };

      scope.$watch('myChildren', function(newVal) {
        if (!newVal) return;
        // mock our service call with timeout
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.children = [{
            id: 1,
            name: "one"
          }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "two"
          }];
          scope.safeApply();
        }, 400)

      });
    }
  }

})
```

Here is a non working example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ZidQ4oBdpYxdg5Fyqe0P?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was much simpler than I thought.

```
        template: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            return tElement.html();
        }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nzvl83hlmjqO0uy08T9h?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Example using directive template](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqm6EFiogj4TuryLWhoq?p=preview)

I haven't use transclude, i usually put all my html in either the template or templateUrl

If i need to 'dynamically' change my html base on something i will build a different directive and use an ng-switch or ngShow/ngHide   it's easier to debug

Comment: Although it works, it doesn't answer my question about using the contents of the directive element for the template.

Comment: by using transclude you are getting access to scope 'outside' of the directive. the transclude is just going to wrap the html with the directive template. the scope that is in the html on your page is available to your controller - not your directive - that's why it isn't working

Comment: I've tried all kinds of different scenarios to be able to use the inside contents of the directive element as the template.  That was just the last iteration and just decided to leave it.

Comment: Is that because you don't want the html for the directive outside of that page?

Comment: What do you mean?  The directive is actually calling a CMS to get some information from child content nodes.  What the user wants to do with it is up in the air, in my case I'm just doing a repeat, but it could be anything.

Comment: You said your wanting to use the html inside the div that your directive is applied to. i was just curious as to why you wouldn't use the directives template for that? Is it because you don't want to html inside the div to by anywhere but on that page? (meaning you don't want to get it from the template or templateUrl of the directive)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47690/discussion-between-lucuma-and-mark-sullivan)